# how to create overlay view for camera and access its methods in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, camera-overlay

hi i have searched lot of for custom camera overlay view. i have find almost many sample projects but i can't still get perfect answer as i want to get. My question is i want to implement custom camera like `instagram` or `picyou` or other social networking apps on button click open custom camera using camera overlay view. i have created custom camera it works fine but i want to access the buttons actions like on capturing image it should navigate to other view by using `UINavigationController` but its not working.i have used this code for calling camera overlay view.

```
-(void)OpenCamera
{
    //create an overlay view instance
    OverlayView *overlay = [[OverlayView alloc]
                            initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGTH)];

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init]; 
    picker.delegate = self; 
    //        picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.allowsEditing = NO;
    if (([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])) 
    {
        //set source to video!
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        //hide all controls
        picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
        picker.navigationBarHidden = YES;
        picker.toolbarHidden = YES;
        //make the video preview full size
        picker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
        picker.cameraViewTransform =
        CGAffineTransformScale(picker.cameraViewTransform,
                               CAMERA_TRANSFORM_X,
                               CAMERA_TRANSFORM_Y);
        //set our custom overlay view
        picker.cameraOverlayView = overlay;
//        picker.delegate = overlay;

//        UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:picker];

        //show picker
        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];  
    }
    else
    {
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
        picker.delegate = self;
        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    }
    [picker release];
}
```

and this is my camera overlay view .m file code i have used `@interface OverlayView : UIView`

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
    //clear the background color of the overlay
//    self.opaque = NO;
//    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    UIToolbar *toolbar = [UIToolbar new];

    toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;

    // create a bordered style button with custom title

    UIBarButtonItem *Cancel = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel"

                                                                  style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered    

                                                                 target:self

                                                                 action:@selector(btnCancel:)] autorelease];

    UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

    UIBarButtonItem *Camera = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera target:self action:@selector(btnCapture:)] autorelease]; 

    UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

    UIBarButtonItem *Album = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Gallery"

                                                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered

                                                                  target:self

                                                                  action:@selector(btnLibrary:)] autorelease];

    NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 

                      Cancel,
                      flexibleSpace1,
                      Camera,
                      flexibleSpace2,
                      Album,

                      nil];

    toolbar.items = items;

    // size up the toolbar and set its frame

    // please not that it will work only for views without Navigation toolbars. 

    [toolbar sizeToFit];

    CGFloat toolbarHeight = [toolbar frame].size.height;

    CGRect mainViewBounds = self.bounds;

    [toolbar setFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(mainViewBounds),

                                 CGRectGetMinY(mainViewBounds) + CGRectGetHeight(mainViewBounds) - (toolbarHeight),

                                 CGRectGetWidth(mainViewBounds),

                                 toolbarHeight)];

    [self addSubview:toolbar];
}
return self;
}

-(void)btnLibrary:(id)sender
{

}

-(void)btnCapture:(id)sender
{

}

-(void)btnCancel:(id)sender
{
//    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

its all working fine but as i said i want to access buttons methods and the UINavigationController for changing the view like `instagram` and `picyou` its not working properly can you guide me how to navigate to another view.?

Comment: thanx it is working fine but how can i remove the front rear button.i want to remove front rear button on the overlay view of camera